# Why isn't my Java GUI GridBagLayout putting my JPanel Grid in the middle of the frame?

Tags: java, user-interface, grid

I created a grid, extending JPanel overriding graphics, and I added to a JPanel which is a GridBagLayout and added the JPanel to the JFrame. But only part of the grid shows up, rest all hidden in the right bottom corner and top left corner of the grid touching the middle of the JPanel.

JFrame's : setSize(500, 300);

JPanel's: setSize(250, 250);

Been trying to figure it out but couldn't... please help.

edit: Here is the following code

```
public class Start extends JFrame{
 public Start(){
  setSize(500, 300);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  JPanel jp = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
  jp.add(grid);
  add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  setVisible(true);
 }
}

//main method calling new Start();

public class DrawGrid extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setSize(250, 250); 
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        //Grid algorithm here 20 x 20
    }
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses. Also take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). Swing components present sizing hints to the layout manager via there `preferred/minimum/maximumSize` properties

Comment: Yes,Please Provide a full Example or a bigger code snippet

Comment: Without more code it's difficult to say, but I'm going to guess it's how you've initialised your GridBagLayout.

Comment: @MadProgrammer eddited

Comment: Please consider providing the grid code

Answer (score 2):

Do NOT, EVER, change the state of ANY UI component from within a paint method, this could cause the component to be invalidated and one or more repaint requests raised, resulting in an infinite loop of paint requests that will cause you PC to implode...well, at least it will eventually consume your CPU...

Your `DrawGrid` has not defined preferred/minimum/maximum size hints for the layout managers to use.

Using `setSize` won't do anything, as it will be overridden by the layout manager

Instead, override the `getPreferredSize` method of your component and return a "preferred" size to the layout manager

```
public class DrawGrid extends JPanel{

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(250, 250);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        //Grid algorithm here 20 x 20
    }
```

Note, sizing hints are just that, they are HINTS, layout managers are permitted to ignore one or more of them at their discretion...

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you!! It works, but what does Dimension in front of getPreferredSize() represent?